# BEAM SQL and RECORD column type

Tags: apache-beam, beam-sql

I am trying to select records from a data file into a PCollection using Beam SQL.

My data file has the below AVRO schema:

"name":"str-field",
"type":[
"null",
"string"
],
"default":null
},
{
"name":"myRecord",
"type":[
"null",
{
"type":"record",
"name":"myRecord",
"fields":[
{
"name":"stringInRecord",
"type":"string"
},
{
"name":"intInRecord",
"type":"int"
},

My Beam SQL is something like this:
SELECT str-field, myRecord from Datafile

But, Beam does not recognize myRecord as a RECORD type. Is there anything wrong here? Or, is it that BeamSQL does not support "RECORD" type?